# How to use jQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I did not manage to use jquery in rails
Here the necessary files

> in the head of application layout, I have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

> application.js has

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

> box.js has

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");    
});
```

> box.html.erb

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Box have necessary height,width,bg-color vs in css file.
I just want the box fade out when I click but I don't know what I did wrong.
I also have the jquery-rails gem in the gemfile

Comment: If you 'Inspect' the element using developer tools on your development machine, is `box.js` being included? Does the box appear at all?

Comment: I think box.js is included in the application.js because of the require_tree, am I wrong ? I can see the box in the view

Comment: box.js is in the same folder with application.js, assets/javascripts/

Comment: In development, it will include the files separately by default. Use the 'Network' tab in Chrome developer tools to double check if box.js is being included, if not, check the content of `application.js` to see if your `box.js` code is present. Does the box itself appear on the page?

Comment: There is nothing in the Network tab except from an empty table, but I can see the code in Elements tab. I will give the content of application.js already, you mean something different ?

Comment: With the network tab open, refresh the page.

Comment: there is nothing included in application.js

Comment: And is `box.js` included?

Comment: yes box.js is included, I can see the code in box.js in network tab

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the class name, and nothing to do with Rails.

Swap;

```
<div class=".box"></div>
```

To;

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Because `.box` is just another syntax for saying "the HTML element with the class of `box`".

Comment: the equivalent of `.box` is `*[class~='box']`

Comment: Sorry I write here wrongly, I will edit that part, the problem is different unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Add jQuery Ui in your project and then check. For effects and animations you need to have jQuery UI.

Comment: I try to install jquery-ui-rails gem, but when I included `//= require jquery.ui.all` in the application.js, I get the error,  **couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' with type 'application/javascript'**

Comment: //= require jquery-ui just use this and restart your rails server and check again.

Comment: I did it now but did not work, the problem can be different

Comment: Is your Box.js file in a sub directory in assets/javascripts directory ?

Comment: Yes the problem is not that, is it about including something about jquery in the head? or is it enough to include `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: yes its enough. Require jquery-ui right after jquery and a suggestion remove //= require_tree . and manually require box.js file as //= require box at the end of application.js file and try again. I hope this will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87783/discussion-between-muhammad-junaid-and-ramazan-zor).

Comment: still didn't work :( , I have require jquery-ujs after jquery. must be a simple problem I think but I can't see anyway